# Angular - can't access to a json-returned class specific value (angular 5, entity framework core with c# back-end)

Tags: c#, json, angular, entity-framework-core, http-get

I am new to Angular and I'm trying to extend the Google's Angular ["Tour of Heroes" example](https://angular.io/tutorial).

I have actually adapted this example to an Entity Framework core-based back-end.

Right now, my application is getting heroes from a database by using Entity Framework core and I have also created a relation with a new table, that contains heroes' powers (a hero can have a power and a power can have more than a hero).

I have encountered an issue in displaying this powers on a list.
My .ts class is this:

```
export class Power {
    id: number;
    powerdescription: string;
    hero: Hero[];
}
```

And the JSON returned by the service is like this:

```
[
    {"id":1,"powerDescription":"PowerA","hero":[]},
    {"id":2,"powerDescription":"PowerB","hero":[]},
    {"id":3,"powerDescription":"PowerC","hero":[]},
    {"id":4,"powerDescription":"PowerD","hero":[]}
]
```

The method I use to get the powers is this:

```
/** GET powers from the server */
getPowers(): Observable<Power[]> {
    return this.http.get<Power[]>(this.powersUrl)
            .pipe(
                tap(powers => this.log(`fetched powers`)),
                catchError(this.handleError('getPowers', []))
            );
}
```

I also share with you my back-end "Power" class:

```
[Table("Power")]
public partial class Power
{

    public Power()
    {
        Hero = new HashSet<Hero>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PowerDescription { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Hero> Hero { get; set; }
}
```

and my controller's get method:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    var powers = _context.Powers;
    return Ok(powers);
}
```

The problem is that if I try to access at a power.description, I can't get anything.
Actually, I think the problem may be caused by the empty hero array in the end of the JSON (Power0 is used by 25 heroes right now).

How can I fix this?

PS: let me know if you need more information

**UPDATE:**
I'm using a dynamic list to display the powers. here's the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let power of powers">
            <span class="badge"> power id = {{power.id}} </span>
            <span class="badge"> power desc = {{power.powerdescription}} </span>
            <span class="badge"> power heroes = {{power.hero}} </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The result of this is that I have got only the id displayed but not the description

Comment: <ul><li *ngFor="let power of list">{{power.description}}</li></ul>


list = [
    {"id":1,"description":"PowerA","hero":[]},
    {"id":2,"description":"PowerB","hero":[]},
    {"id":3,"description":"PowerC","hero":[]},
    {"id":4,"description":"PowerD","hero":[]}
   ]

Comment: Did you try this?

Comment: @AkshathKumar i've tried and this works, but it works only with a static list... The strange thing about this is that it's actually formatted like the JSON that I obtain from the service.
The problem persists with the JSON...have you got any idea of where  and or what could be the problem?

Comment: do you mean the problem exists when you fetch it from the backend?

Comment: @AkshathKumar yes, when i fetch it from the back-end the description seems to be always void when i try to access to it, but the json objects "description" field always contains something (E.G.: "Power0",Power1",...).
Also, the chrome console tells me that it failed to fetch powers, but i get the right IDs displayed by using the html code that i've added to the question under "update 1". Other fields are actually void

Comment: please check the link. Is this what you expect? I have added a zone so that it will be sync with the template when I get the data from an async call

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xmepqz

Comment: @AkshathKumar i've just tried using your code but it still don't work...
To answer to your question, the result on your example is what I expect to see as a result on my app (but in my app, this doesn't work).
Have you got any other ideas about this problem?

Comment: did you get the proper JSON data from the backend? Please double check once. 

In your component 
getPowers().subscribe((powers) => this.zone.run(() => {this.powers = powers}))

Comment: @AkshathKumar I've tried but it doesn't work... Got any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer to my own question.

The answer is just: "pay attention to uppercase".

I explain myself better.

The JSON generated by the back-end changes the first uppercase of the variables, but not other eventual uppercases in the variable name.

E.G.: if a var is named "Value", the JSON variable will be named "value" but if a variable is named "MyValue", the JSON variable will be named "myValue".
The front-end angular variables MUST be named exactly like the JSON variables, because the association between the JSON value and the angular variable is made by name and it's case sensitive.

Hope this answer will be helpful to other angular beginners too